# Symfony2 Form overwrites 'GET Request Parameters'

Tags: forms, symfony

In a view I have a Symfony2 Form (using GET, not POST) and also some pre-existing request parameters.

If I submit the Form the pre-existing request parameters are overwritten.

Is there a way to merge the new with the existing parameters?

**Edit:**

I actually don't think code will work here as this seems to be the default behavior.

Let's assume I have the following url:

```
localProject/app_dev.php/products/index?sort=id&direction=asc&page=1
```

I have a Form (Build with Symfony Formbuilder). when I submit the Form I have the following url:

```
localProject/app_dev.php/products/index?formField1=someThing
```

But I want the url to be like:

```
localProject/app_dev.php/products/index?sort=id&direction=asc&page=1&formField1=someThing
```

Comment: Could you supply your controller/form code here? It's really hard to guess what's your problem.

Comment: @kix Thanks for your comment. I edited my post above. Hopefully it is understandable now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thiago Rodrigues answer pushed me towards the right direction. Here is how I solved it.

I added the `sort` and `direction` fields as hidden fields to my form.

```
class AttributeFilterType extends AbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        if ($request->get('sort')) {
            $builder->add('sort', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => $request->get('sort'),
            ));
            $builder->add('direction', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => $request->get('direction'),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

To make sure that the Values of the Form are not overwritten by old legacy values of the form. I made changes to the request, as follows (note: attributeFilter is the name of my Form):

```
/**
 * This function will analyze the given request.
 *
 * It will correct and set the settings of the given sort Values
 *
 * If the request contains sort and attributeFilter, always take the sort and overwrite the attributeFilter
 * If only the attributeFilter is given, set the sort=Attributefilter
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
protected function manipulateParameterBag(Request $request)
{
    $parameterBag = $request->query;

    $sort = $parameterBag->get('sort');
    $direction = $parameterBag->get('direction');
    $attributeFilter = $parameterBag->get('attributeFilter');
    if ($sort && $direction) {
        if ($attributeFilter) {
            $attributeFilter['sort'] = $sort;
            $attributeFilter['direction'] = $direction;
            $parameterBag->set('attributeFilter', $attributeFilter);
        }
    } elseif ($attributeFilter) {
        $parameterBag->set('sort', $attributeFilter['sort']);
        $parameterBag->set('direction', $attributeFilter['direction']);
    }

    $request->query = $parameterBag;
    return $request;
}
```

Hope this helps the next person that tries to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

If sort, page and direction parameters are not fields of your form, you can do this inside your controller:

```
$data = array();
$form = $this->createForm(
    new MyFormType(), 
    $data,
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'action' => $this->generateUrl(
        'this_route_name', 
            array('sort' => 'id', 'direction' => 'asc', 'page' => 1)
        )
    )
);
```

Another approach is add these parameters as fields of form. In this way, you do this in controller:

```
$defaultData = array(
    'page' => 1,
    'direction' => 'asc',
    'sort' => 'id',
);

// $defaultData are used as default values by form. They are overridden by values received in request, if sent.

$form = $this->createForm(
    new MyFormType(), 
    $defaultData, 
    array(
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi Thiago, thank you for your answer, however none of your described ways worked for me... Your first way seemed to add the parameters to the action, however when submitting the form the parameters are gone ...